# How to create auto generate code in django

Tags: python, django

I have a company, department, and item list. in item list company and department are foreign keys. so when I add an item into the item list, item will generate a code for itself automatically like from company name's 3 alphabets, department name's 3 alphabets and 4 or 5 digits no. starting from 0001 and auto-increment. each company item will start from 0001. As an example: If a company is "ABCDE" and the department is "Finance" the code will be auto-generated like ABC-Fin-0001. is there any way to get these things done?

## Model_Class

```
class Item(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank =True)
    item_choice = (
        ('IT','IT'), 
        ('Electronics', 'Electronics'),
    )
    item_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank =True, choices = item_choice )
    code = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null =True,blank=True)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete = models.SET_NULL,null= True, blank=True)
```

## My_view

```
def item_entry(request):
    title = 'Add Item'

    form = ItemForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Successfully Saved')

        return redirect('/item_list')
    context = {
        "title": title, "form":form
    }

    return render(request,'item_entry.html', context)
```

## Form_View

```
class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ("item_name","item_type", "code","company","department",)
```

## Template_view

```
<table>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Item Name</th>

                    <th>Item Type</th>
                    <th>Code</th>
                    <th>Company</th>
                    <th>Department</th>

                </tr>
                {% for instance in queryset %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
                    <td><a href="{% url 'item_edit' pk=instance.pk %}"> {{instance.item_name}}</a></td>
                    <td>{{instance.item_type}}</td>
                    <td>{{instance.code}}</td>
                    <td>{{instance.company}}</td>
                    <td> {{instance.department}}</td>

                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: First it would be nice to show what you've tried yourself. Second, if you really have no idea how to start, try this: instead of saving the entire string in `code`, only save the sequential number in code. That way, you can do `Item.objects.filter(company=abc_company, department=finance_dept).order_by('code').values('code').last()` to get the last code and increment it for the next item. Also you can make `code`, `company` and `department` unique together.

Comment: actually, I have no idea how to do that. That's why asking for help to get some ideas or knowledge. what if I only just save the sequential no. only in my UI then what will be generated in my backend the whole code no. with the company name and department?

Comment: You can define a python `@property` on your model that creates the string from the fields of the model. Just need to `return f"{self.company}_{self.department}_{self.code}"` for example.

Comment: @dirkgroten hey i am able to use the string code but unable to generate the auto-increment like 00001. should I declare the code as the primary key ? is a wise decision? how can I easily regulate the auto-increment no, along with the string?